# How can I create a chaotic structure from a triangled mesh

Tags: mesh

I have a cube, which I subdivided into smaller parts, which I then changed into triangles. I would like to reproduce something like this : https://www.pinterest.fr/pin/392657661240154630/

Now my cube is subdivided, though its faces are flat. How can I do to create those "bumbs" and "cavities" ?

Comment: Welcome to blender SE. There are numerous ways to create detail in meshes. You could apply a Displace Modifier on the and then modify the texture. You could tab into Edit mode, select some random vertices and scale them in or out: repeat as needed. You could go into Sculpt mode and using a low resolution, large brush, sculpt details into the mesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood the question

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> Add cube.

In edit mode press <kbd>W</kbd> subdivide

Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and play with the settings with **Fractal** and **Along Normal**

[image]

To make the faces from Quad to triangulate In Edit mode Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or In edit mode -> Mesh -> Faces -> Triangulate faces.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A Non-destructive way is to add a Displace modifier

[image]

With a simple procedural noise in the Texture slot. (go to the texture tab in the properties panel to select the type)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The direct way to do this is to use Proportional Editing set to Random.

You can activate Proportional Editing, in Edit Mode, by pressing <kbd>O</kbd> while your mouse cursor is over the 3d Viewer. Or, you can go to the bottom menu bar and click on the button in the middle, with the little gray circle in it, as shown in the gif movie. You want the Random setting in the pop-up.

Then select any vertex, and press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it. When Proportional Editing is active, a circle appears around the cursor showing the range within which it affects the mesh. You can increase and decrease that distance by rolling the mouse wheel up and down. I just made it big enough to surround the whole cube, and shifted a vertex a bit. Then I did that a few times, selecting different vertices and shifting in different directions.

[image]